# Magento 2 Admin form wysiwyg field width problem

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, adminform

I have added a WYSIWYG field in my custom admin form but it's taking the full width of the form instead of matching other fields width.

[image: Here is the screen-shot]

Here is what I am using for this in `ui_component`

```
<field name="description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Job Description</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">job</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">130</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">description</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made it work as the way I wanted. Just added text field with WYSIWYG enabled.

```
<field name="description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">job</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Job Description</item>

                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">description</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">130</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Answer (score 3):

Magento2 admin forms evolve and a given answer is not perhaps the best for the latest version.

In 2.3.x the crucial part is `template`:

```
    <field name="description" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="80">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Fabric</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
            </validation>
            <label translate="true">Description</label>
            <dataScope>description</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <wysiwyg>
                <settings>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

Comment: Still the width issue is not resolved :(

Comment: That should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

In order to display wysiwyg Ui Component smaller, You will require to add a Template into Field Tag like this:

> template="ui/form/field

Here's the how you can use it.

```
<field name="ad_description" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="50" formElement="wysiwyg">
```

I've tried in Magento 2.4 in Admin Ui Form.